# How do I lock down a particular API gateway path to only be called by a particular lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, openapi, api-gateway

Apologies for my naivety, i'm new to aws-cloudformation

the scenario:

1. I have a lambda function (F1)
2. In a separate stack in the same AWS account I have an API gateway(API1) connected to another lambda function(F2)

the second stack template.yaml :

```
Resources:
#############
 # Rest  Api #
 #############
 API1:
   Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
   Properties:
     StageName: Prod
     DefinitionBody:
       "Fn::Transform":
         Name: "AWS::Include"
         Parameters:
           Location: !Ref OpenApiDefinitionLocation

 ##############
 # Functions #
 #############
   F2:
   Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
   Properties:
     CodeUri: lambda/dist
     Handler: handler/code.foo
     Role: !GetAtt F2Role.Arn
     Events:
       bobEvents:
         Type: Api
         Properties:
           Path: /bob/{proxy+}
           Method: any
           RestApiId: !Ref API1
```

and the openapi.yml :

```
openapi: "3.0.1"
paths:
    /jim/{bar+}:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${foo.Arn}/invocations"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST" 
        type: "aws_proxy"
  /bob/{proxy+}:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      parameters:
        - name: "proxy"
          in: "path"
          required: true
          schema:
            type: "string"
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${F2.Arn}/invocations"
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "post"
        contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
        type: "aws_proxy"
```

I want to make the path `/bob/{proxy+}` so that it is only accessible by F1 (in the first stack) (or just lockdown so it is not accessible from outside my AWS account).  but I still want `/jim/{bar+}`  to be publicly accessible.

any advice or pointers would be amazing,  thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need to deploy a separate, private API gateway for the private endpoints. Or just have one Lambda call the other Lambda directly without going through API Gateway.

Comment: thanks, yep, but the first Lambda has to call an API gateway for "reasons" and  having a separate API gateway is ugly :( .  I just thought there might be an easy way to  "lockdown" a individual path rather than the whole gateway,  it seems like it would be a common use case?